# Asynchronously load a Sandboxed Web Part

Tags: web-part, sandbox-solution

I'm wondering if there is an way to load custom Sandboxed Web Parts asynchronously. I have done this earlier with ScriptManager, I understand that this not possible with Sandboxed solutions. And these days with more SharePoint Online users it would be interesting to know how this is done.

Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these out:

[Add JavaScript Files Once To A Page - SharePoint Sandbox Solutions](http://www.lightningtools.com/blog/archive/2009/12/06/add-javascript-files-once-to-a-page---sharepoint-sandbox.aspx)

[TechNet: How To Find Control in Sandbox Visual Webpart Template](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/sharepoint2010programming/thread/d7441348-868d-4aff-8eaa-98412034f643)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for reference. See [How to Answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.